# How to speed up clustering analysis in R?

Tags: r, clustering, cross-validation, model-based-clustering

I am conducting a simulation study, which involves several clustering methods such as model-based clustering method (MBCM). However, there is a big problem I find that MBCM runs so slowly (might be due to the EM algorithm).  I have tried my best to avoid for loop in my simulation setting but it still takes me forever. For example, I simulate 100 datasets and each data set contains 1000 subjects. This tiny simulation took me around **879** minutes to complete. I can't image how much time will take me to complete 1000 simulated datasets. Does anyone have a better idea to speed up the clustering analysis in R?

many many thanks
Tu

Comment: Out of curiosity, what package did you use for model-based clustering, `mclust`?

Comment: yes. I was using mclust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should find out where the bottleneck is by using Rprof() and other profiling options and take it from there.

In addition, this sounds like an ["embarassingly parallel"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problem, where one analysis of the dataset does not depend on the others analysis - therefore perfectly suited for parallel processing, either using multiple cores (package multicore et al) or on a high performance cluster (see [High Performance Computinr in R task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) for further details).